# Unable to submit form using jQuery after creating a hidden 'submit field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to submit the form using `jQuery.submit()` after creating a hidden field named `submit`. But after I remove the hidden field, it works perfectly, the form gets submitted.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" id="btn-next" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right; padding-left: 30px; padding-right: 30px">Next</button>
    <button type="button" id="btn-prev" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">Previous</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="sagar" value="submit" />
    <!-- Add WordPress Nonce -->
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-product' ); ?>                                   
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
// Handle the 'next' button click.
    jQuery('#btn-next').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // Validate the product details.
        var form = document.querySelector('form');
        if (! validateForm(form, constraints[currentProductState]) ){
            return;
        }

        if ( currentProductState == 2) {
            jQuery("#form-add-product").submit();
            return;
        }

        // If the form is ok, hide the current view.
        jQuery(addProductState[currentProductState]).hide();

        // Increment the state by 1.
        if (currentProductState < 2) {
            currentProductState++;
        }



        // Show the next view.
        jQuery(addProductState[currentProductState]).show();
        // Set the progress bar.
        jQuery(progressBarList[currentProductState]).addClass("active");

    });
```

Comment: That's interesting, but I'm wondering if currentProductState has something to do with it.  What is that anyway?

Comment: The currentProductState is just a counter to track the state of the multi step form. The jQuery('#from-add-product').submit() get executed but the form is not submited.

Comment: What is #from-add-product?  I'm guessing that's the form?  You might have to put in more of your HTML, if you can.

Comment: Yeah its the form id.

Comment: There must be something getting in the way.  I would need to see more code to be sure.  If there's too much code to post, can you put up a link of your site?